# How to override a multi-line string with --set in helm install command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to install a helm with a dynamic "project_id" flag on deploy time inside the `rawConfig` multi-line string

Example `values.yaml`

```
sinks:
  console:
    type: "console"
    inputs: ["kafka"]
    rawConfig: |
      target = "stdout"

      encoding.codec = "json"

  stackdriver:
    type: "gcp_stackdriver_logs"
    inputs: ["kafka"]
    rawConfig: |
      healthcheck = true
      log_id = "mirth-channels-log"
      project_id = "my_project"
      resource.type = "k8s_cluster"
```

How do I override this value of `project_id` in rawConfig? I'm trying to do this:

```
 helm install vector helm/vector --values helm/vector-agent/values.yaml -n my-namespace --set sinks.stackdriver.rawConfig='\nlog_id\ =\ "mirth-channels-log"\nproject_id\ =\ "my_project_test"\nresource.type\ =\ "k8s_cluster"\n'
```

But it does not work

Comment: The correct way of doing that is via a 2nd `--values` file since the `--set` syntax is really only for very simple things, and becomes unwieldy when used in any kind of complicated way

Answer (score 4):

Use second --values like following:

```
# values_patch.yaml
sinks:
  stackdriver:
    rawConfig: |
      healthcheck = true
      log_id = "mirth-channels-log"
      project_id = "SOME_OTHER_PROJECT_ID"
      resource.type = "k8s_cluster"
```

```
$ helm install [...] --values values_patch.yaml
```

Comment: this is also valid for kafka server.properties definitions
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/2575818836eeff7d53aa30ec6c6457543e43a526/bitnami/kafka/values.yaml#L113

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best way, but you can use a separate multiline variable for that:

```sh
export MULTILINE_VALUE=$(cat <<EOF                     
healthcheck = true 
log_id = "mirth-channels-log" 
project_id = "my_project_test"
resource.type = "k8s_cluster" 
EOF
)

helm install vector helm/vector --values helm/vector-agent/values.yaml -n my-namespace \
--set sinks.stackdriver.rawConfig=$MULTILINE_VALUE
```