# Can not set custom parameters(numPartitions,defaultReplicationFactor) for bitnami/kafka

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I created an Azure K8s cluster.
Then I install the bitnami/kafka by using helm:

```
 helm install kafka bitnami/kafka --set replicaCount=3,provisioning.enabled=true,provisioning.replicationFactor=3,provisioning.numPartitions=3,extraConfig="logRetentionHours=-1,logRetentionBytes=2199023985135,offsetsTopicReplicationFactor=3"
```

However, if deploy the Kafdrop ui and check the test topic that auto-created when my nestjs project sends the message to kafka cluster, it shows the topic has one Partition and one Replication.

The custom parameters are not in effect.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I highly recommend using a values file, not using set argument. That way you can backup your config outside your local shell history. Beyond that, why bitnami charts over Strimzi? Or Azure Eventhub so you don't need to manage a cluster on your own?

Answer (score 1):

You should compare your parameters in this file.
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/kafka/values.yaml

`replicaCount` parameter does not exist. The correct parameters are `controller.replicaCount`, `broker.replicaCount`, `zookeeper.replicaCount`.

`extraConfig` parameter requires values to be separated from each other by newline or if on one line, must use `;`. The correct configuration should be

```
extraConfig="logRetentionHours=-1;logRetentionBytes=2199023985135;offsetsTopicReplicationFactor=3"
```

If you want to configure `extraConfig` parameter on multiple lines, you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64699548/14312225).
In addtion, you can use the following to compare whether the values ​​have been applied.

```
helm template kafka bitnami/kafka > output-default.yaml
helm template kafka bitnami/kafka --set replicaCount=3,provisioning.enabled=true,provisioning.replicationFactor=3,provisioning.numPartitions=3,extraConfig="logRetentionHours=-1,logRetentionBytes=2199023985135,offsetsTopicReplicationFactor=3" > output-custom.yaml
```

Then, compare 2 files `output-default.yaml` and `output-custom.yaml` to check the difference.